# remote add still fetches tags with --no-tags option

Tags: git, git-remote

[EDIT: use a smaller repository; add output]

On a freshly created repository, this command still fetches all tags:

```
git remote add --fetch --no-tags  upstream https://github.com/phdru/mimedecode.git
```

Isn't the point of the `--no-tags` option not to fetch tags?  Am I missing something?

```
% git --version
git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)
% git remote add --fetch --no-tags origin https://github.com/phdru/mimedecode.git                           Updating origin
remote: Enumerating objects: 1684, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (72/72), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (48/48), done.
remote: Total 1684 (delta 35), reused 54 (delta 22), pack-reused 1612
Receiving objects: 100% (1684/1684), 245.14 KiB | 3.10 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1160/1160), done.
From https://github.com/phdru/mimedecode
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
 * [new tag]         2.7.0      -> 2.7.0
 * [new tag]         2.8.0      -> 2.8.0
 * [new tag]         2.9.0      -> 2.9.0
 * [new tag]         3.0.0      -> 3.0.0
 * [new tag]         3.1.0      -> 3.1.0
 * [new tag]         v2.3.0     -> v2.3.0
 * [new tag]         v2.3.1     -> v2.3.1
 * [new tag]         v2.3.2     -> v2.3.2
 * [new tag]         v2.3.3     -> v2.3.3
 * [new tag]         v2.3.4     -> v2.3.4
 * [new tag]         v2.3.5     -> v2.3.5
 * [new tag]         v2.3.6     -> v2.3.6
 * [new tag]         v2.3.7     -> v2.3.7
 * [new tag]         v2.3.8     -> v2.3.8
 * [new tag]         v2.4.0     -> v2.4.0
 * [new tag]         v2.5.0     -> v2.5.0
 * [new tag]         v2.6.0     -> v2.6.0
```

I observe the same behavior with non-Apple git 2.33.0.

Comment: May you share the output of this command?

Comment: Edited to use the smaller repository and to add output.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm seeing similar behavior with Git 2.39.2 (Debian Bookworm package). The initial 'remote add --fetch --no-tags' does not fetch tags, and it properly stores the tagOpt in .git/config (confirmed with 'git config remote.upstream.tagOpt'), but a subsequent 'git fetch upstream' fetches tags, even with '--no-tags' added explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, I'm just abusing the answer box to publish formatted text.

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in test-git/.git/

$ git remote add --fetch --no-tags origin https://github.com/phdru/mimedecode.git
Updating origin
remote: Enumerating objects: 1667, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (71/71), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (47/47), done.
remote: Total 1667 (delta 35), reused 53 (delta 22), pack-reused 1596
Receiving objects: 100% (1667/1667), 239.77 KiB | 288.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1160/1160), done.
From https://github.com/phdru/mimedecode
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master

$ rm -rf .git 

$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in test-git/.git/

$ git remote add --fetch origin https://github.com/phdru/mimedecode.git
Updating origin
remote: Enumerating objects: 1684, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (88/88), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (64/64), done.
remote: Total 1684 (delta 35), reused 70 (delta 22), pack-reused 1596
Receiving objects: 100% (1684/1684), 245.14 KiB | 445.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1160/1160), done.
From https://github.com/phdru/mimedecode
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
 * [new tag]         2.7.0      -> 2.7.0
 * [new tag]         2.8.0      -> 2.8.0
 * [new tag]         2.9.0      -> 2.9.0
 * [new tag]         3.0.0      -> 3.0.0
 * [new tag]         3.1.0      -> 3.1.0
 * [new tag]         v2.3.0     -> v2.3.0
 * [new tag]         v2.3.1     -> v2.3.1
 * [new tag]         v2.3.2     -> v2.3.2
 * [new tag]         v2.3.3     -> v2.3.3
 * [new tag]         v2.3.4     -> v2.3.4
 * [new tag]         v2.3.5     -> v2.3.5
 * [new tag]         v2.3.6     -> v2.3.6
 * [new tag]         v2.3.7     -> v2.3.7
 * [new tag]         v2.3.8     -> v2.3.8
 * [new tag]         v2.4.0     -> v2.4.0
 * [new tag]         v2.5.0     -> v2.5.0
 * [new tag]         v2.6.0     -> v2.6.0
```

The bottom line: `git remote add --fetch --no-tags` works for me as designed.

PS. I used a small repository of mine to make the tests run faster.